# How to use json in ios 5.1?

Tags: ios5

I'am first time implementing json in my app.

and in my app I have to receive parameters from   webservice to my app  and  but I am not able to find any tutorial in which I can pass parameters from my app in ios5.1

so is there any tutorial on net from which I can get tutorial which is useful to me.

I tried to find using google but i did not succeed.
Please i need help. I don't have idea about json ios5.1

Answer (score 0):

I know you can use [SB JSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/). And a guide should be on the Github page.

If SBJSon isn't working for you, try [Working with JSON in iOS 5 Tutoria](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) instead.

Comment: i I use ios 5.1 with xcode 4.3 which does not support USB Json. IT uses NSJSONSerialization and I tried the following code but I can not see a result has